# creating a c/c++ project in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide

I have been using Eclipse to create java projects. However when I click on create new project, there is no option to create a new c/c++ project.

I tried to install it on my existing eclipse go to Help >> Install New software >> Add and add the link: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno

But the link http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno is giving 404 error.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

Comment: How is this related to `java`?

Comment: @Naveen the option of creating c/c++ project itself is not coming ..Can you please tell how to install the c/c++ plugin in eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Andremoniy , removed.

Comment: @Naveen , yes , i went to this link , but if you click that
p2 software repository: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno., its giving 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Why just not to download ready to use CDT:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplerr

Comment: Hi harvyS, i am bit noob in installing stuff,but i went to the link  :http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junosr2 
After downloading the .tar.gz file for linux 64 bit machine, 
I tried to Help >> Install New software >> local , then browse the location of extracted file , but still its giving error No software site found at this location..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the update for MARS

Help >> Install New software >> Add "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars"

after that check --> Programming languages ---> C/C++ Development Tools

and install it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Help >> Install New software >> Add "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"

after that check --> Programming languages ---> C/C++ Development Tools

and install it

Comment: Yes, it is. But in question Juno link is written , so I put correct link to repo of Juno.